# How can I change the color of my Graphics in one class by preforming an action from another class?

Tags: java, user-interface, events, graphic

I'm new to java and desperate, so here we go!!!
I am trying to change the color of my GUI contents when I click a certain option in my menu, but I am unsure how to. Here is the menu with its ActionPreform methods

```
    public JMenuBar makeMenuBar(DrawHere drawHTree) {

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu menSize = new JMenu("Color");
    menuBar.add(menSize);

    JMenuItem mitSmall = new JMenuItem("Black");
    mitSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //Do stuff here...
        }

    });
    menSize.add(mitSmall);

    JMenuItem mitMedium = new JMenuItem("Red");
    mitMedium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // Do stuff here...
        }

    });
    menSize.add(mitMedium);

    JMenuItem mitLarge = new JMenuItem("Cyan");
    mitLarge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // Do stuff here...
        }

    });
    menSize.add(mitLarge);

    return menuBar;
}
```

And here is a snippet of the class whose graphics color I wish to change

```
    private void drawHTree(Point location) {

    int x = (int)location.getX();

    int y = (int)location.getY();

    int boxSize = (int)(this.getHeight()*HTREE_SIZE);

    // Rough draft test: 13:50.55 for n = 13
    // Optimized test: 11:42.42 for n = 13
    int n = 5;
    _drawHTree(n,x,y,boxSize);
}

private void _drawHTree(int n, int x, int y, int boxSize) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Graphics brush = this.getGraphics();

    //brush.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(1,1,1));

    brush.setColor(Color.RED);// <------- NEED HELP HERE! I WANT TO  
                                      // BE ABLE OT CHANGE THIS COLOR 

    ((Graphics2D) brush).draw(new Line2D.Double
            (x, y, x + boxSize, y));
    ((Graphics2D) brush).draw(new Line2D.Double
            (x + boxSize, y - boxSize/2, x + boxSize, y + boxSize/2));
    ((Graphics2D) brush).draw(new Line2D.Double
            (x , y - boxSize/2, x, y + boxSize/2));

    // compute x- and y-coordinates of the 4 half-size H-trees
    int x1 = x - boxSize/2;
    int x2 = x + boxSize/2;
    int y1 = y - boxSize/2;
    int y2 = y + boxSize/2;

    // recursively draw 4 half-size H-trees of order n-1
    _drawHTree(n-1, x1, y1, boxSize/2);
    _drawHTree(n-1, x1, y2, boxSize/2);   
    _drawHTree(n-1, x2 + boxSize/2, y1, boxSize/2);    
    _drawHTree(n-1, x2 + boxSize/2, y2, boxSize/2);    
}
```

So, anyone have any ideas? Thanks ;D

Comment: Let's start with - `this.getGraphics();` been a terriblly bad idea - take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more ideas about how painting works and how you can work with it

Comment: *"I am trying to change the color of my GUI contents when I click a certain option in my menu"* - What you need is a model.  This is shared between your classes, it provides a means for other classes to make changes to it. The model then provides an observer pattern to generate events/notifications when it's changed, so interested parties can make updates to themselves based on the new state of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not jus decleare a Color variable and write a setter for that variable. Then instead of writing direct color in the

```
brush.setColor(Color.RED);
```

use

```
 brush.setColor(myColor);
```

Decleare your variable

```
Color myColor;

public void setMyColor(Color myColor){
     this.mayCOlor = myColor;
```

in the actionPerfomed just call this method

Comment: Thank you! I was having such a mental block, but t hat is what I needed!